# Ошибка при работе с swiftmailer

Tags: php

Цель: переслать сообщение при помощи swiftmailer. 
Вот код

```
require_once 'swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
         $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.yandex.com', 465))
          ->setUserName('pasha@tut.by')
          ->setPassword('e10');    
         $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
         $message = (new Swift_Message('Web Lead'))
         ->setFrom (['pasha@tut.by' => 'Web Leads from Port city Technology'])
         ->setTo ([$myEmail,'pasha@tut.by' => "Web Leads from Port city Technology"])
         ->setBody('text/html');
         $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class
>   Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator does not exist in
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php:309
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(309):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('Egulias\EmailVa...') #1
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(323):
>   Swift_DependencyContainer->createNewInstance('email.validator') #2
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(114):
>   Swift_DependencyContainer->createSharedInstance('email.validator') #3
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(371):
>   Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup('email.validator') #4
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(348):
>   Swift_DependencyContainer->lookupRecursive('email.validator') #5
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(129):
>   Swift_DependencyC in
>   /var/www/html/firstTask/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php
>   on line 309

и вот строка ошибки

```
> private function createNewInstance($itemName)
>     {
>         $reflector = new ReflectionClass($this->store[$itemName]['className']);/////вот она <--------------------------
>         if ($reflector->getConstructor()) {
>             return $reflector->newInstanceArgs(
>                 $this->createDependenciesFor($itemName)
>                 );
>         }
> 
>         return $reflector->newInstance();
>     }
```

Comment: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/943

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему скачав более старую версию Swiftmailer. 
Вот ссылкочка, кому надо https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tree/4.1

Answer (score 0):

Пользоваться старой версией - не самый лучший вариант, поскольку в старых версиях могут быть уязвимости. Вот [подробный мануал](https://blog.lisogorsky.ru/send-mail-by-smtp), с примером, на русском языке, как настроить Swift Mailer.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer" zoompage-fontsize="14)